# How to link additional library with orocos component project in linux?

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to link libcurl with my orocos component but it cant be link. Please suggest me where to give its lib and include path

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238133/how-to-link-additional-library-with-orocos-component-project-in-linux?/) by [Mihir5293](https://answers.ros.org/users/27295/mihir5293/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-29**:
This isn't a question about ROS, and there isn't enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the normal [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)/[target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) cmake macros for this:

```
include_directories(${ADDITIONAL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
orocos_component(foo foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo ${ADDITIONAL_LIBRARIES_TO_LINK_WITH})
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mihir5293](https://answers.ros.org/users/27295/mihir5293/) on 2016-06-28**:
I tried to link libcurl with it. but always got error of undefined reference

**Comment by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on 2016-06-28**:
Did you use [find_package(curl)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCURL.html) to find curl?

**Comment by [Mihir5293](https://answers.ros.org/users/27295/mihir5293/) on 2016-06-29**:
yes i find_package(curl) and it would be found but still same problem. libcurl cannot be link with project when i make amd make install it.!